# How to include a file automatically in PHP?

Tags: php, configuration, include

I would like to have a "site.php" file (similar to Python) that is automatically included on every invocation, e.g. command-line execution or HTTP request.  This file contains several important replacement functions which need to be available to both existing applications and new.

(I.e. I need to include this file without modifying any files related to the applications in use.)

Is this possible?  And if so, how?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In php.ini set

```
auto_prepend_file="/path/to/site.php"
```

Answer (score 1):

EDITED - Read the initial post a bit too hastily, apologize.

In php.ini, instead..

```
auto_prepend_file="/path/to/site.php"
```

Comment: Ah thanks for pointing it out - I guess I skimmed the post too quickly!