# How to handle absolute URLs in localhost

Tags: php, html, localhost, absolute-path

I'm trying to use absolute URLs throughout my PHP website to make sure that the paths to pages and images are always accurate/working, no matter where you are in the file hierarchy.

I struggle to find the best, most maintainable way to handle that.

Here is an example of what I have at the moment :

`require_once 'http://localhost/Website/includes/init.php';`

"Website" in this case is the name of the directory I created for this project. The main problem with this method is that if I change the directory name, I'll have to search&replace a thousand of occurences throughout all the pages.

After searching on StackOverflow, I found what seems to be a better way to handle this :

```
define("LOCAL", "http://localhost/Website/");
define("WEB", "http://foo.bar");
$environment = LOCAL; //change to WEB if you're live
```

Whenever I want to create a link, I use this synthax :

`require_once($environment . 'includes/init.php');`

This works quite well, but I was wondering if it really was the correct way to do this.

If it is, I'm strill struggling with one detail : **how can I include this portion of code, where the constants and variable are defined, in all of my pages?** I can't use an include, because for that include to work everywhere in the website it would need the constants and variables that are in the file that it's trying to call, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your `ini` or `.htacces` file with `auto_prepend_file`.  [PHP auto include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034907/php-auto-include)