# How to include php file automatically?

Tags: php, include

I create a **functions.php** in my project's root folder. My project has some other folder like **inc** and in this folder there are 2 folder like **folder-1** and **folder-2**. So when I create a php file like **something.php**, I include this to my **functions.php** file like **include_once 'inc/folder-1/something.php'**. But when I create many of php file, every time I need to include or require this files to my function file.

**Is there any way to include all php file together dynamically?**

Like, I create..

something-1.php in folder-1

something-2.php in folder-1

something-3.php in folder-1

nothing-1.php in folder-2

nothing-2.php in folder-2

nothing-3.php in folder-2

Now I include this file to my function file by writing like this..

include_once 'inc/folder-1/something-1.php';

include_once 'inc/folder-1/something-2.php';

include_once 'inc/folder-1/something-3.php';

include_once 'inc/folder-2/nothing-1.php';

include_once 'inc/folder-2/nothing-2.php';

include_once 'inc/folder-2/nothing-3.php';

**Is there any solution to avoid this manual including system?**

Like, when I create a new file in those folder, this will automatically include in functions.php file, and when I delete this, there will be no impact on my project...

Comment: Composer implements several common autoloading standards. https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading

Comment: not sure your building the best structure but you should look at: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `glob`

**For folder-1**

```
foreach (glob("inc/folder-1/*.php") as $yourfilename)
{
    include_once $yourfilename;
}
```

**For folder-2**

```
foreach (glob("inc/folder-2/*.php") as $yourfilename)
{
    include_once $yourfilename;
}
```

Comment: this is a rather basic approach to a problem that has been solved by autoloading

Answer (score 0):

First create a file name it something like 'allfiles.php' then include all the files you want include to the file example. include 'inc/folder-1/something.php' follow by all the file up to the last nothing.php, now save it when ever you want include just include the "allfiles.php" all the files will be included hope it helps?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the auto_prepend_file directive in your php.ini file,

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file

reference : [PHP auto include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034907/php-auto-include)

make sure before removing that the file has no dependency on it